# Is to use 'of' meaning 'from' old-fashioned?

Tags: prepositions, expressions

Is there any difference in tone between the two expressions?

> May I ask you a big favor?
>
> May I ask a big favor of you?

Is it right that there is a rule to say in this way? Or is it just the way to avoid repeating the same?

> “May I ask you a question?”
> “Sorry, I'm busy now.”
> “OK, then I'll ask the question of Tom.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does sound old-fashioned, but it's still used, mostly as a polite form of speech in formal or professional contexts.

To avoid repetition in your third example, I would simply say:

> OK, then I'll ask Tom.

Both you and the listener know you want to ask a question, so there's no need to repeat the word. The meaning is implied:

> OK, then I'll ask Tom [the question].

However, the form *ask a [favor/question] of* is more commonly used with "favor" than with "question," which sounds even more old-fashioned.

This sentence sounds somewhat old-fashioned but very polite:

> I'd like to ask a favor of Tom.

But this sentence sounds much more old-fashioned and pretentious:

> I'd like to ask a question of Tom.